# KeyErrors and how to raise a KeyError

Tags: python, exception

For my homework assignment, I am told to raise a key error if the key(text) the user enters contains any non alphabetic characters and reprompt. So far I have this which seems to work but obviously doesn't use the expected try/except structure

```
key=input("Please enter the key word you want to use: ")
ok=key.isalpha()
while (ok==False):
    print("The key you entered is invalid. Please try again")
    key=input("Please enter the key word you want to use")
```

Comment: This is a bad question for SO: (1) it's homework, (2) the OP's original code isn't syntactically valid, (3) there's no clear question here, (4) the only answer is just a homework solution without explaining anything.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is **not** appropriate usage of `KeyError` (it's supposed to be used for dict lookups, or similar situations), but if it is what you have been asked to do then try something like this :

```
def prompt_thing():
    s = raw_input("Please enter the key word you want to use: ")
    if s == '' or not s.isalnum():
        print("The key you entered is invalid. Please try again")
        raise KeyError('non-alphanumeric character in input')
    return s

s = None
while s is None:
    try:
        s = prompt_thing()
    except KeyError:
        pass
```

Comment: the OP just gave a code fragment for which we don't know the context...charitably assume subsequent lines do create a dict...

Comment: Unfortunately, a quick read of "an inappropriate" can be (mis)parsed as "an appropriate" - I know because I was so stunned that I re-read the answer (and saw I had misparsed!)